# Ignoring reference type in mapping entity to DTO

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm creating a .NET Core web API. How can I ignore reference of a supplier from product entity class when mapping an entity to DTO? From my code, you can see that I have a supplier selling collection of products. Each product got a reference to the supplier.

This is the response that I want to get.

```
{
  "companyName": "",
  "contactName": "",
  "contactTitle": "",
  "city": "",
  "country": "",
  "phone": "",
  "fax": "",
  "products":
  [
    {   
      "productName": "",
      "supplierId": 0,
      "unitPrice": 00.00,
      "package": "",
      "isDiscontinued": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently, the response throws an error it gets tries to get supplier info.

```
{
  "companyName": "",
  "contactName": "",
  "contactTitle": "",
  "city": "",
  "country": "",
  "phone": "",
  "fax": "",
  "products":
  [
    {   
      "productName": "",
      "supplierId": 0,
      "unitPrice": 00.00,
      "package": "",
      "isDiscontinued": false,
      // i get error here
      "supplier" : ""
    }
  ]
}
```

classes

```
public class Supplier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactTitle { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public string Package { get; set; }]
    public bool IsDiscontinued { get; set; }
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
}


public class SupplierDTO
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactTitle { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductDTO> Products { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDTO
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public string Package { get; set; }
    public bool IsDiscontinued { get; set; }
    public SupplierDTO Supplier { get; set; }
}


public class SuppliersProfile: Profile
{
    public SuppliersProfile()
    {

     // ignore Supplier reference from Product when accessing each Product 
        field from the ICollection product
     CreateMap<Supplier, SupplierDTO>()
            .ReverseMap();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to ignore the member:

```
public class SuppliersProfile: Profile
{
    public SuppliersProfile()
    {

     // ignore Supplier reference from Product when accessing each Product 
        field from the ICollection product
        CreateMap<Product, ProductDTO>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Supplier, c => c.Ignore());

        CreateMap<Supplier, SupplierDTO>().Include<Product, ProductDTO>();
            .ReverseMap();

    }
}
```

Sorry don't see that. Try to create a separate map for the product and include it in the supplier. So I'm not an expert on auto mapper. see the doku for more infors: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Nested-mappings.html

Comment: There is no supplier field in Supplier class